# Linking text to one another within documents

Tags: hyperlinks, comments

I'm making a package extension for an IDE with a functionality that allows the end user to link separate pieces of syntax to one another, and post a comment/question regarding those two pieces of syntax. I'm looking for examples as to how this is done for design guidance. So far I've explored bookmarking in Google Docs and Word and the copying issue id functionality in Pivotal Labs, but nothing has been super applicable. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can I ask why users would want to link separate syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io/) includes related CSS styles inline:

[image: Adobe Brackets inline code screenshot]

---

[GitHub](https://github.com/features) allow users to add comments to code:

[image: GitHub comments screenshot]

---

Another option may be to put code side-by-side:

[image: icdiff screenshot]